# Why special Characters is invalid button content?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, prism

[image]

What the problem with this << give the button name like this not accepted in xaml
< , > , & , "" and space Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain this behavior we need to know the following:

> Button is one of content controls, which are simply controls that are
>   constrained to contain a single item. Content controls all derive from
>   System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl, which has a Content property
>   of type Object that contains the single item. Because a content
>   control’s single item can be any arbitrary object, the control can
>   contain a potentially large tree of objects. There just can be only
>   one direct child.

If you open an Error list window, you can see many errors there, not just that one in your picture.

For me, it's

- White space is missing.
- The value "<" is not valid in an attribute.
- **Expecting an XML tag name.**
- The token "" HorizontalAlignment="Left" (omitted for brevity) is unexpected.
- 2x The open angle bracket character '<' is not valid in an attribute. **It should be written as &lt;**.

Now, you could guess why it's not a valid character, not to mention that a solution is also described there in the last error. The compiler is confused, it thinks that you are nesting in a new UI element.

As for the other question about not allowed characters in a name, it's obvious. They are not allowed to be used in names in C# or VB.NET either. If you try it in XAML, it will produce an error saying what's allowed. It's just a decision made by a team who designed this. There are languages where these characters can be used as identifiers for objects.

There's a more elaborative explanation in the following [blog post](http://ojanacek.blogspot.cz/2015/01/button-with-in-content.html).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<Button Content="&lt;&lt;"/>
```

Comment: Not a problem :-) I'm glad my headaches trying to do the same thing have saved you one.

Comment: @Dhru'soni Read my answer if you want know why your solution is not working. That's your question "What the problem", not "How to fix it".

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Yes i Read it . and i understand it . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try `&#171;` for << and `&#187;` for >> this are called "ISO Latin-1 code" for more checkout this link:
http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html

Answer (score 1):

I have just written an answer which is

> I guess you should use < instead.

but actually I mean

> I guess you should use &lt; instead.

The characters **&lt;** in my answer were escaped to **<**.

Comment: No one could knew what you actually ment. But it's how it is. +1 for trying again.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek Got it:-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button>&lt;</Button>
```